# Use require('../assets/file.mp3') in ES6

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, expo

I am trying to load a local mp3 file to be played using Expo Audio SDK. 
Here's an example from the documentation:

```
const soundObject = new Audio.Sound();
try {
  await soundObject.loadAsync(require('./assets/sounds/hello.mp3'));
  await soundObject.playAsync();
  // Your sound is playing!
} catch (error) {
  // An error occurred!
}
```

I am also using ES6 in my project which makes `require` unavailable.
Is there any way I could still load a local resource in ES6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, `require` is still a thing in ES6. I've used it plenty of times throughout my apps. The example should work, have you tried it?